# Visual Studio 2019 not Recognizing new Files Pulled from GitHub

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019, viewpage

I am working in a team with a project where GitHub is used. The project type is Google Gloud Project MVC5 .NET Framework 4.5.2.

When new changes are pulled down from GitHub, the new files are not detected as the correct filetype, resulting in the Visual Studio code validation being completely abscent when editing the new files.

As seen in the picture, the issue concerns `.cshtml` files with Razor code but also `.cs` files.
[image: Solution Explorer. "Show All Files" needs to be clicked to even view the files in the Solution Explorer.]

Comment: Try to include them into the project

Comment: I would assume that your solution uses [old](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file) `csproj` format, so everything needs to be included manually, what could have happened - somebody has added and committed new files but forgot to commit new `csproj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guru Stron suggested, the old `.csproj` was not committed (The project was made in VS17 but we are now all using VS19.

The issue was resolved by commiting the `.sln` file and the `.csproj` file from the instance where the most recent changes had been created.